# Animate buttons to slide and change nicely

Tags: android, button, sdk, native

I saw this design mockup [here](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/62329/screenshots/1362247/setup.gif) and I think the button flow is superb. Any idea how it can be done on android? Or is it iOS specific? Or not doable at all? I don't have much experience in frontend android design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly doable. I would look into view property animators for android. You could go about this different ways. One way would be to animate the view directly. So say you have 2 buttons at the bottom like in the link you posted. When your activity or fragment is created, initialize the buttons but then set their visibility to View.INVISIBLE. That way they won't be visible to the user and they won't be clickable.

Then you can animate the buttons using xml animations. You'll need to make an animation that will make the buttons appear like they are coming up. So in your project, make a folder anim under resources and then make a file called slide_up_animation. It should look something like this:
slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

Note that in your layout (use a frame layout), your buttons should be laid out to be at the bottom. This includes the "setup", "detail" and "next" button. You just have to make them all invisible at the beginning.  Then the animation will start at a y position 100% above your views length, so it will apppear like they are sliding up.

Next in the on click method of the button you want to initialize the sliding to the left animation just load the animation and start it when the button is clicked. That animation will look something like:

slide_left.xml

```
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-200%p"
            android:duration="500" />
```

So to summarize your acitivity will look something like this.

```
public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {

   private Button nextButton;
   private Button detailButton;
   private Button cancelButton;
   private Animation slideUp;
   private Animation slideLeft;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
   nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton) // ...you get the idea.

   nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) // do this for all buttons
   //...other code

   slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.slide_up);
   slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.slide_left);

//slide buttons up
   slideButtonsUp();

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick() {
         slideLeft();
        }

     });

   } 

   private void slideButtonsUp() {

    if(nextButton != null && detailButton != null) {
       nextButton.clearAnimations();
       detailButton.clearAnimations();
       nextButton.startAnimation(slideUp);
       detailButton.startAnimation(slideUp);

       nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       detailButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

   } 

   private void slideLeft() {

    nextButton.clearAnimations();
       detailButton.clearAnimations();

     nextButton.startAnimation(slideLeft);
     detailButton.startAnimation(slideLeft);
     nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    detailButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    cancelButton.startAnimation(slideLeft);
    cancelButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


   } 
}
```

It may not be elegant or pretty  but I've used similar techniques in my apps and it works quite well and looks good to the user. It shouldn't be a huge performance issue either but I could be wrong. Hope that helps.

Comment: do you think maybe using a fragment would be better? I've never used it, but I've been reading about it

Comment: Usinga fragment for just the buttons? Or for the whole view?

Comment: for that bottom view with the buttons

Comment: That could actually work. All youd have to do is put a frame layout at the bottom of your parent layout and then add the fragment. The fragment manager could then handle the transition animations